# {(¬A v ¬B) → C, D & ¬C} ⊢ A

Tags: logic

{(¬A v ¬B) → C, D & ¬C} ⊢ A

this is my   try

1- (¬A v ¬B)

2- A

3- ¬B            (  1,2  vE  )

but I'm stuck on the others , please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You have to assume* $\lnot A$ :

1) $(¬A \lor ¬B) \to C$ - premise

2) $D \land ¬C$ --- premise

3) $\lnot A$ --- assumed [a]

4) $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$ --- from 3) by $\lor$I

5) $C$ --- from 1) and 4) by $\to$E

6) $\lnot C$ --- from 2) by $\land$E

7) $\lnot \lnot A$ from 3), 5) and 6) by $\lnot$I, discharging [a]

> > 8) $A$ --- from 7) by *Double Negation*.